# Change css depending on span value

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a span and a div. I need to make it where if the value of span is 123, change the css of the div to display:none;

I'm trying to do it with jQuery, but I cannot see where I am going wrong.
Here is my code:

(by the way, I'm using jQuery no conflict)

```
      <script>
        jQuery(function ($) {
jQuery('span.specialspan').filter(function(){
    return $.trim($(this).text()) == '123'
}).css('display', 'none');
});
</script>

<span class="specialspan">123</span>

<div id="specialdiv">Foo</div>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in your console like `jQuery is not a function` ?

Comment: What you have works, however you're setting the display property on the span, not the div

Comment: Do you only have the one span/div that you need to compare, or multiple span/div groups?

Comment: `if($('.specialspan').text() == '123') { $('#specialdiv').css('display', 'none');}`  ?? but you could better use [hide();](http://www.api.jquery.com/hide/) `if($('.specialspan').text() == '123') { $('#specialdiv').hide();}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `each()` to check each `span` and `next()` to hide `specialdiv` after span with 123

```js
$('span').each(function() {
  if ($.trim($(this).text()) == '123') {
    $(this).next('.specialdiv').css('display', 'none');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="specialspan"> 123 </span>
<div class="specialdiv">Foo</div>
<br>
<span class="specialspan">lorem</span>
<div class="specialdiv">Lorem</div>
```

Comment: Works, thank you! Will accept the answer in a few minutes!

Comment: This assumes that `.sepcialspan` and `#specialdiv` are siblings. Also, you wrote `.specialdiv` instead of `#specialdiv`.